# Why is the Rabin mapping not a permutation over $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$

Tags: rabin-cryptosystem

Why is the Rabin mapping: $f_i(x_i)=x_i^2  \bmod N_i$  not a Permutation over $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the Rabin mapping: $f_i(x_i)=x_i^2  \bmod N_i$  not a Permutation over $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$?

Because it maps distinct inputs to the same output.

For example, $f_i(1) = f_i(N_i - 1)$, with both being 1

Comment: or, general case: $f_i(j) = f_i(N-j)$